# File Indexing software - Design

Tags: c#, software-design

I am currently developing a file indexing system. I have an interface IDiskDrive that can get immediate file items (files/folders). The interface definition is as follows...

```
public interface IDiskDrive
{
  bool IsReady { get; }

  string Name { get; }
  string VolumeLabel { get; }
  string VolumeLabelName { get; }

  DiskDriveType Type { get; }
  FolderPath RootFolder { get; }

  DiskDriveUsage Usage { get; }

  IEnumerable<IFileItem> GetImmediateFileItems(FolderPath path);
}
```

The ability to read all file/folders is complete and works correctly. Now, I need to actually index the file files and folders. Looking ahead I know I will need some reporting tools. This leads me to think I need another abstraction, based upon IDiskDrive that can read/populate. I also need the ability to select drives for indexing.

My question is should my new class inherit IDiskDrive or should I use composition (possibly a decorator)?

```
// inheritance
class IndexedDiskDrive : IDiskDrive
{
   public IndexedDiskDrive(IDiskDrive drive)
   {
      ...
   }

   public int Id {get; internal set; }  // database id
   public bool Selected { get; internal set; }
   public DateTime? DateLastIndexed { get; internal set; }

   // IDiskDrive implementation
   public bool IsReady
   {
     get { return this.Drive.IsReady; }
   }
}
```

or composition...

```
class IndexedDiskDrive
{
  public IndexDiskDrive(IDiskDrive drive)
  {
    this.Value = drive;
  }

  public IDiskDrive Value
  {
    get;
    private set;
  }

  // additional properties
  public int Id { get; internal set; }
  public bool Selected { get; internal set;}
  public DateTime DateLastIndexed { get; internal set; }      
}
```

Note:
  I need access to the underlying IDiskDrive for the UI.
For example, I request user to select drives to index. I initially supply a list of local drives and the ability to add network drives. To try and keep code simple, I thought the idea of a new class with a selected property might help.
This allows the GUI to enumerate a list of IndexedDiskDrives and set/clear the select property.

Comment: you could have another interface IIndexed and the instantiating classes implementing both if they support indexing

Comment: You should probably change the title of this question to make it a better headline for your question

Answer (score 0):

In both examples you expose the IDiskDrive object from the other object. In the first case you inherit from the same inteface, which means you expose the same methods and in the other case you expose the object via a property.

I don't see a reason yet why you want to do this.

It sounds like a typical constructor DI case to me. Just have a new interface for your new class which is doing a different job and hence requires a different contract, and if it needs the IDiskDrive object as a dependency, then just inject it via the constructor and leave it as it is.

P.S.: I know this is not something you have asked, but you might be interested in Lucense.NET, which is a .NET library to index files. They might have already solved your problem for your:

### http://lucenenet.apache.org/

EDIT:

From your current class design I would do the following:

```
void Main()
{
    // Use IoC container in real app:
    var diskDrive = new DiskDrive(...);
    var fileIndexer = new FileIndexer();

    var fileItems = diskDrive.GetImmediateFileItems(filePath);
    fileIndexer.IndexFiles(fileItems);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public interface IDiskDrive
{
  bool IsReady { get; }

  string Name { get; }
  string VolumeLabel { get; }
  string VolumeLabelName { get; }

  DiskDriveType Type { get; }
  FolderPath RootFolder { get; }

  DiskDriveUsage Usage { get; }

  IEnumerable<IFileItem> GetImmediateFileItems(FolderPath path);
}

public interface IFileIndexer
{
    void IndexFiles(IEnumerable<IFileItem> files);
}

public class FileIndexer : IFileIndexer
{
    public void IndexFiles(IEnumerable<IFileItem> files)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I was kind of heading along these lines, the only real difference being I have an interface, 
   public interface IIndexDiskDriveContents
   {
      void IndexDiskDriveContents(IDiskDrive drive);
   }